# how to resolve uiresponderview exception in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios8, keyboard

am getting this error -[__NSCFDictionary _responderWindow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a68ff60 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary _responderWindow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a68ff60'

Comment: Where you were calling responderWindow method in your code???

Comment: at the time of typing in keyboard this expextion is happening